# How to get element as space in list of tags using xpath, if the element is not present

Tags: java, xml, list, xpath, nodelist

I have a use case where my XML is like this

```xml
<IR>
        <name>abc</name>
        <Level></Level>
      
</IR>
<IR>
        <name>xyz</name> 
        <Level>LVL00006</Level>     
</IR>
```

I am using below code to extract information of level.

```java
public class TestUseCases {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Document document;
    try {
        document = factory.newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    
    String xpathExpression = "";
    Map<String, List<String>> iRValues = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    xpathExpression = "(/IR/Level/text())";
    
        iRValues.put("REQLVL", evaluateXPath(document, xpathExpression));
        
        System.out.println(iRValues);
    } catch (SupportException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static List<String> evaluateXPath(Document document, String xpathExpression) throws SupportException {
    // Create XPathFactory object
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    // Create XPath object
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        // Create XPathExpression object
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
        // Evaluate expression result on XML document
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(nodes.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            String item = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
            System.out.println(item);
            if (item.trim().isEmpty()) {
                values.add(SupportConstants.EMPTY_SPACE);
            } else {
                values.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            }
        }

    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        throw new SupportException(SupportExceptionMessage.ERROR_IN_READING_RESPONSE_FROM_CM);
    }
    return values;
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
LVL00006
{REQLVL=[LVL00006]}
```

The problem is because first level tag is empty, I get a list which has only one element and I am not able to know whether the element is of abc or xyz. Is there a way so that I can put space if the tag is empty?

I am expecting list as [" ", LVL00006].

Comment: You could consider to simply select e.g. `//IR/Level` with XPath, that way, for your sample, the node list would contain two element nodes and the value you want (e.g. either the empty string or the value `LVL00006` could be read out on the DOM API level with `nodes.item(i).getTextContent()` or with a relative XPath expression selecting `string()` on `nodes.item(i)`.

Comment: Another option would be to move to XPath 2 or 3 where you can select e.g. `//IR/Level/string()` directly as a sequence of string. That is not possible with the JAXP, XPath 1 API but certainly e.g. with Saxon's s9api.